# Express the $\nabla\cdot(A(\nabla))$ using the curl operator like the identity $\nabla\times(\nabla\times ) = \nabla(\nabla\cdot ) -\nabla^2$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $A$ be a $3\times 3$ real constant symmetric positive definite matrix.
I want to check if I could express the operator $\nabla\cdot(A\nabla)$ with the help of the operators $\nabla\times$, $\nabla\cdot$ and $\nabla$ (If I take $A=I$ in such an expression, I will find the well-known formula $\nabla\times(\nabla\times ) = \nabla(\nabla\cdot ) -\nabla^2$, so I want a generalisation of that last identity).

Comment: in $div(A\nabla)$ , how is A defined?

Comment: @cineel it is a mistake, $M$ should be $A$, I edited it

Comment: when A=I, we get div(grad). how does that relate to the well-known formula?

Comment: @cineel div(grad) is the Laplace operator $\Delta$, the well-known formula is curl curl= grad (div) - $\Delta$